# Programmatically insert images with the aloha editor

Tags: javascript, aloha-editor

I want to include images in an aloha editable after a `drop` event, thus not using the toolbar button.

While some aloha commands may be executed programmatically, there is not so much doc about it and one must look into the code.

With the debugger i found that the relevant function is [here](https://github.com/alohaeditor/Aloha-Editor/blob/6327bf9c79fbf3e269ef45e459537d3cfa74d405/src/plugins/common/image/lib/image-plugin.js#L986) so now i would go for copying the `insertImg` function body somewhere in my code and build my function.

On the other hand it would be much cleaner to reuse that code calling something like

```
Aloha.plugins.image.insertImg();
```

In a way similar to how it is done [here](https://github.com/alohaeditor/Aloha-Editor/blob/6327bf9c79fbf3e269ef45e459537d3cfa74d405/src/plugins/common/image/lib/image-floatingMenu.js#L126). Is it possible to do such a thing?

Answer (score 0):

A colleague explained me that there is nothing special required in order to insert an image. The function [used by aloha](https://github.com/alohaeditor/Aloha-Editor/blob/6327bf9c79fbf3e269ef45e459537d3cfa74d405/src/plugins/common/image/lib/image-plugin.js#L1000) is just a way to substitute jQuery and is not necessary.

Once the `common/image` plugin is loaded, it is sufficient to append an `<img>` tag inside the editable, also with jQuery, and the plugin will be triggered on it, adding the resize handle and showing the image toolbar when needed.